# Implementing the idea of category in C++ at compile time

Tags: c++, category-theory

I'm trying to play around with implementing the idea of category (as in Category Theory) in C++.
I'm not sure it's possible but here is an implementation that for examples allows you define a category.

```
#include <functional>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

// A category is formed by:
// - A collection of objects
// - A collection of arrows, such that each arrow has a source object and a target object
// - A composition law for arrows that is associative
// - An identity arrow for each object

template <typename Object, typename Arrow>
struct Category {
    std::function<Object(Arrow)> source;
    std::function<Object(Arrow)> target;
    std::function<Arrow(Object)> identity;
    std::function<Arrow(Arrow, Arrow)> compose;
};

namespace FiniteSet 
{
    // An arrow in the category of finite sets is a triple (domains set, codomain set, function)
    template <typename T>
    struct Arrow {
    std::vector<T> source;
    std::vector<T> target;
    std::function<T(T)> function;
    };

    template <typename T>
    Arrow<T> identity(std::vector<T> set) {
    return Arrow<T>{set, set, [](T x) { return x; }};
    }

    template <typename T>
    Arrow<T> compose(Arrow<T> f, Arrow<T> g) {
    if (f.source != g.target) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Composition is not defined");
    };
        // We follow the right-to-left convention
    return Arrow<T>{f.source, g.target, [f, g](T x) { return f.function(g.function(x)); }};
    }

    template <typename T>
    std::vector<T> source(Arrow<T> f) { return f.source; }

    template <typename T>
    std::vector<T> target(Arrow<T> f) { return f.target; }
}



int main ()
{
    auto finset = Category<std::vector<int>, FiniteSet::Arrow<int>>{
    FiniteSet::source<int>,
    FiniteSet::target<int>,
    FiniteSet::identity<int>,
    FiniteSet::compose<int>
    };
}
```

This allows you to define the notion of a category (e.g. the category of finite sets of integers) at *runtime*, however this doesn't need to be the case since all information is available before compilation.

How can I implement the same idea at compile time (ideally by allowing to define something like a `FiniteSet<int>`)? Would it be possible to do this using templates + C++20 concepts?

Comment: Why do you think this is done at run time?

Comment: Well for example, in my implementation the category of finite sets is instantiated as a runtime variable. Instead, I would like that "information" to be encoded in the type system at compile time. E.g. something like `FiniteSet<int> finiteSetCat;`

Comment: Which operations do you want to run on those structures? constexpr and templates are ways to do it at compile time. Your categories seem to be quite general. Often also types of programming languages are modeled with category theory as a more specific case.

Comment: A category of finite sets is a category. Now if only we had a way to express the *is-a* relationship in C++... perhaps in a way that bundles data and related operations together in a convenient package...

Comment: Data can be stored as member variables of a type or as template parameters of a type or as traits of a type. Such a type can be self-contained or you can have a data structure of either several types or instances of types. For a data structure of types they could refer with `using` within the namespace of types to each other.

Comment: *"(ideally by allowing to define something like a `FiniteSet<int>`)"* -- Since you want the template at the `FiniteSet` level, why not just do it? It would make the syntax simpler than your current approach of making each member a template.